# Not able to set css top and left value in jquery through variables

Tags: jquery, css

I'm Not able to set css top and left value in jquery

```
 $('#myImages img').hover(function(){ 
        var top1 = $(this).offset().top;
        var left1 = $(this).offset().left;

        $('#closeImage').css({
            "opacity" : "1",
            "top" : top1,
            "left" : left1
        });
    },function() {

        });
});
```

Don't know what is wrong the close image is no where to be seen.
I guess there is something wrong in setting the below values
"top" : top1,
"left" : left1

Comment: what type of `position` does `#closeImage` have? also try   `top:top1+'px', left:left1+'px', position:'absolute'`

Comment: #closeImage{
 opacity:0; 
 position : absolute;
 top : 15px;
 right : 35px;
 z-index:1; 
}   @ cheery top top1 +'px' its not working ... error console in firefox says top1 is undefined.

Comment: Could you please reconstruct your problem at jsfiddle.net ? `top1` should be definitely defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `});` it should be:

```
$('#myImages img').hover(function() {
    var top1 = $(this).offset().top;
    var left1 = $(this).offset().left;

    $('#closeImage').css({
        "opacity": "1",
        "top": top1,
        "left": left1
    });
}, function() {

});
```